# How to get the inactivity of the user for eg. when the device is still and not moving?

Tags: android

Trying to create my first android application, I am creating an application that will track a user who hasn't moved in a while and notify them to move. I need to ask how can I achieve this ? What I am essentially looking here is a timer starts when the device is inactive and when the device moves the counter stops and that data is stored. Are there any API's for this ?

**Google Fit API ?**

Many of the sleep tracking applications do this, they track the device is stable at night and when the user picks up the phone they end the timer and they display the time user was asleep at night.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the Activity Recognition API, which is part of Google Play Services.

You would want to listen for the [`STILL`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html#STILL) event.

About using this API:
[Here's a tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8sugXgUVEI)
[Here's a Google sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/ActivityRecognition)

Some additional info:

You might want to combine this with a timer (like no change in `STILL` after X minutes or hours), and also take the time into account: The device will obviously not be moving at 3 AM, but you don't want the user to be moving at that time, since he is sleeping.

Comment: Thanks a ton, man. Will definitely look into this, if this works, I owe you man, thanks for helping a fella out who is just dabbling in android. You are awesome.

My twitter ID is @nam009 , whats yours ?